# stinky stem walls!

Tags: concrete, foundation

Our house has stem walls that have a musty/acrid odor. Looking for advice about possible causes, and what to do about it.

House was built in 1979, is 2-story, bottom story is slab slightly below grade (really at grade at one end), with stem walls all the way around. So the downstairs is not really a basement -- it's finished and always has been AFAIK -- and includes an attached garage.

The odor is hard to describe. It's sort of mildewy but not just that. Maybe mildew mixed with the smell of a urinal with one of those white cakes in it. Maybe not that bad, but close. It's not overpowering, but very noticeable when the house has been closed up. The smell is strongest in the garage, which is also the only room with long runs of exposed and unsealed stem wall. In other downstairs rooms, the stem wall is either drywalled over, or painted/sealed.

It took me a while to find the source of the odor by sniffing around at all the surfaces, but it's definitely the stem wall. When I put my nose against it, the odor is very strong. The drywall above the stem wall doesn't really smell. And I opened up the framed walls in a few places - no obvious rot inside and no strong odor from inside. The slab (which is exposed both in the garage and in an interior room where we just removed the flooring) also has no real odor. The odor is present in the stem wall on multiple sides of the structure, so it's definitely not a problem in one spot from some spill or animal, etc. There's no noticeable odor upstairs.

I wonder if this is just from moisture seeping in from the outside, or if it's due to some ingredient in the concrete itself. I'm in pacific NW, so plenty of moisture around. There is some evidence of moisture in the stem walls: in the garage the bottom-most drywall fasteners are all somewhat rusted.

Any advice? How do I diagnose the source of the problem? why would the stem wall stink but not the slab?
And how do I get rid of the odor? Should I just seal the concrete on the inside? Or do I need to address the moisture getting in from the outside, or both?

Thanks much!

Comment: Is it a fishy or seaside smell?